# AsyncCache is cleared after app is relaunched

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

I am working on a flutter application. I have a screen which has list of items. I am using `AsyncCache` to avoid making API calls many times and cache the list of items. I have kept a cache duration of 4 hours. This is working fine when the app is open.

However when I close the app and open it again then API call is made again. Is it expected behaviour? I expect the data to be cached till 4 hours are over irrespective of app relaunches.

Please throw some light on this.

Comment: An `AyncCache` is only useful as long as the variable referencing it hasn't been garbage collected - if you want something that instead writes to local storage it needs to be some other implementation. This should be easy to write if you don't mind leaking storage for more than 4 hours while the app isn't open.

Comment: How are you using AsyncCache. I would like to cache API calls but I don't know how to use AsyncCache with FutureBuilder